# Testing Rails REST API with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm building a REST API on Rails, and I'm trying to use RSpec to test it.  I'm using fairly boilerplate auth code:

```
  def authenticate_user_from_token
    pp 'authenticate_user_from_token'
    pp request.headers.inspect
    user = authenticate_with_http_token do |token, options|
      pp token
      user_id = options[:user_id]
      user = user_id && Eater.find_by_id(user_id)

      if user && Devise.secure_compare(user.auth_token, token)
        user
      else
        nil
      end
    end

    @current_user = user
  end
```

This works perfectly if I send requests with curl, but I can't figure out how to pass the auth token in Rspec.  My basic request is this:

```
get '/api/1/users/1'
```

I've tried setting the token using the header method:

```
header 'Authorization: Token token', @token
```

That doesn't work.  I've also tried passing it to the get method as I've seen in some examples:

```
get '/api/1/users/1', :authorization => @token
```

Also doesn't work.  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is this a controller spec or a request spec?

Comment: Request.  I'm trying to test the API by using it as a client would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP parameters are the third argument to `get`, so you need to do something like:

`get '/api/1/users/1', nil, {'Authorization' => @token}`

Depending on the constraints on the key, you may also get away with:

`get '/api/1/users/1', nil, authorization: @token`